# What concept expresses the entropy/system_size ratio?

Tags: entropy, linear-systems

Being entropy an [extensive property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensive_and_extensive_properties), I assume that two systems having the same *absolute* entropy but different sizes (e.g. particles numbers), have in fact a substantial difference regarding its assessed microstates.

But I haven't been able to find any variable expressing such fact. Something like$$
\text{relative entropy} = \frac{\text{absolute entropy}}{\text{size}}
\,,$$noting that "*relative entropy*" is already defined in mathematical statistics, but in a different sense.

What is the formal concept expressing such idea?

Comment: Volumetric entropy (for size). Specific entropy (for weight). Molar entropy (for amount).